# Issues displaying OpenWeatherMap with leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openweathermap

I am practicing on a simple weather app using OWM. I am fetching the coordinates and pass them to a function to display a map using leaflet.

Here is my code

```
function drawMap(lat,lon){

    const mymap = L.map('map').setView([lat, lon],3);

    L.tileLayer(`https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/temp_new/3/1/1.png?appid=${apiKey}`).addTo(mymap);

}
```

My issues are :

-Zoom level is required by leaflet but it's also in the openweather URL so i don't know if i need to put the same or not
-in the url, i'm supposed to put x and y tile coordinates , I don't really understand the required X and Y values and the OWM API doc doesn't really elaborate on those.

Right now , using the values 3/6/1 for example, i get
[image: Result]

The zoom is just the same tiles over and over and you can't make out anything so obviously I'm doing something wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you are describing but normaly you would set template strings in the Tile-Url that can are replaced by leaflet:

```
L.tileLayer(`https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/temp_new/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?appid=${apiKey}`).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand now that i was supposed to use an object in leaflet as a parameter. I got it working